# How to filter Django REST Framework queryset by foreign key of nested object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I have the following Django models:

```
class Pa(models.Model):
   pa_name = models.CharField

class Pb(models.Model):
    pa = models.ForeignKey(Pa, related_name="pbs")
    pb_name = models.CharField()

class Pc(models.Model):
    pb = models.ForeignKey(Pb, related_name="pcs")
    pc_name = models.CharField()
```

The queryset of `Pc` has this structure:

```
[
  { "id": 1,
    "pc_name": "pc_1",
    "pb" = {
      "id": 10,
      "pb_name": "pb_1",
      "pa" : {
        "pa_name" : "pa_1"  # <-- How to filter queryset by pa_name attribute?
      }
    }
  },
  { "id": 2,
    "pc_name": "pc_2",
    "pb" = {
      "id": 20,
      "pb_name": "pb_2",
      "pa" : {
        "pa_name" : "pa_2"
      }
    }
  },
  # ...
]
```

I'd like to return all those `Pcs`, where `pa_name` is `"pa_1"`, i.e. filter over the 2. level nested object.

Answer (score 2):

Possible using a chained filter:

```
pcs = Pc.objects.filter(pb__pa__pa_name=pa_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own filter class then define what you want to filter:

```
import django_filters.rest_framework
import django_filters.filters

class FilterClass(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    pb = django_filters.CharFilter(
        method="filter_pa", label="Pa filter"
    )
    class Meta:
        model = models.Pc
        fields = { 
            "pc_name": ["icontains"],
        }
    
    def filter_pb(self, queryset, field_name, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            pb__pb_name__icontains=value
        ).distinct()

class PC(APIView):
    filterset_class = FilterClass
```

So this filter set will allow you to filter your `pb_name`. Hope this answer will help you to solve your problem.